# Wordpress Woocommerce - Variable product price below title

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Wordpress version: `4.6.1`

Woocommerce Version: `2.6.4`

When using standard woocommerce and you add a variable product with different price values. Woocommerce shows the minimum and maximum prices for that product below the product title . Like so : `€50 - €100`

I added following code to my functions.php file to disable this behavior for variable products:

```
/** Hide Variable prices */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'bbloomer_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'bbloomer_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );

function bbloomer_variation_price_format( $price, $product ) {

 if (is_product()) {
    return $product->get_price();
 } else {
        // Main Price
        $prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
        $price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( '%1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

        // Sale Price
        $prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
        sort( $prices );
        $saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( '%1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

        if ( $price !== $saleprice ) {
        $price = '<del>' . $saleprice . '</del> <ins>' . $price . '</ins>';
        }
        return $price;
         }

}

// show variation price
add_filter('woocommerce_show_variation_price', function() {return true;});

//override woocommerce function
function woocommerce_template_single_price() {
    global $product;
    if ( ! $product->is_type('variable') ) { 
        woocommerce_get_template( 'single-product/price.php' );
    }
}
```

This all works well. But now the variable price is showing below the Product options, like shown in the images below. **I would like to show the variable price below the title.**

**Simple product. I would like to show the price like this on a variable product.**
[image]

**Variable product right now:**
The €150 is a result of selecting the color and size. After i select those values the price appears below the variations. I want this variation price to be shown below the title, like a simple product.

[image]

I spent hours finding how to do it, but the only thing i found was changing the woocommerce-core files. This is not an option because woocommerce needs to be updated.

**UPDATE**

To address the confusion of **@Amy Ling** . i dont want a minimum or maximum price shown. I need the price of the current variation shown below the title. So for example : A shoe is red and size 30 => €150 , A shoe is red and size 40 => €170, etc. A extra image:

[image]

Comment: You have not explained yourself very well. So the price was in the correct location before you added custom code? Can you paste a link to the page with the problem?

Comment: No, the first image is a Simple product. Which shows 1 price and i added it to show where the variable price should be. The second picture shows where the variable price is currently with the custom code. The third picture is without the custom code, which shows 2 different prices, which is not what i want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to the code you have, add the following to your theme `functions.php` file:

```
function shuffle_variable_product_elements(){
    if ( is_product() ) {
        global $post;
        $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
        if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 10 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 20 );

            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 10 );

            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 30 );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'shuffle_variable_product_elements' );
```

**Explanation**

The problem which makes moving these elements slightly complex is that variable products are dynamic and the price element is manipulated with JavaScript in `\woocommerce\assets\js\frontend\add-to-cart-variation.js`. This price element is dynamically placed in `<div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation">` which must stay in the variation's `<form>` element of class 'variations_form'.

So, what I've done with these actions is move the price to the top of the form, because it must stay in the form. Then I've removed the title and excerpt from above the form and added them back in, inside the form.

**These actions may appear above price too.**

The actions I changed above were enough for the theme I was solving this problem on. However, some other functions hooked into the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` action include:

- `woocommerce_template_single_rating`
- `woocommerce_template_single_meta`
- `woocommerce_template_single_sharing`
- `woocommerce_template_single_price` (you already effectively dealt with this one with your own code

Depending on your theme and the WooCommerce settings you use, these may also need to be removed and added back in with the `woocommerce_before_variations_form` action.

Comment: This answer is almost perfect. Also a very clear explanation. But i have 2 problems. On the variable product the product short-summary shows up twice now. 1 time above the title and 1 time below the price. I searched for the hook and it seems like you already removed and added that part back, so not sure why it shows up twice. Also on other product types, like a simple product, my title has dissapeared now.

Comment: Ah. We can circumvent problem number 2 by wrapping the code in an `if()` statement, which checks if the product is variable. Problem number 1 is somewhat dependent on your theme. The line that is failing is `remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );`. This works with default WooCommerce. Your theme may have the excerpt tied to another action or the priority might be different from 20. The correct priority must be set when removing actions.

Comment: Yes the if statement is pretty obvious, sorry about that. I will look in the theme for that same hook and the appropriate property, after that you will get the bounty.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, i tried your if statement, but that doesn't seem to trigger it. i added global $product; to it but that also doesn't trigger the if statement. I did find my priority tho, which is 20. So that part works perfect. It is only the if statement that doesn't trigger right now

Comment: @Christophvh Apologies I was not in front of a computer. I've edited the question with some enhanced code that will properly check for a variable product.

Comment: Ah yes, it needed to be in a custom function, that makes sense. It works great. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Christophvh No worries! Thanks for the sweet sweet bounty reputation!

Comment: Even chatgpt couldnt solve this. thanx @Christophvh

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite WooCommerce template files via your theme folder. This will not affect anything when you do updates to the plugins.

Here is a link that has a detailed documentation on it: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

A lot of the files will have a `do_action('woocommerce_add_this_info_piece');`. You can find out what information gets added to it in the template hooks located at `/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-hooks.php`

**UPDATE**

After downloading WooCommerce and creating a variable and simple product. Both simple and variable pricing already displays right after the title. The code below removes the max pricing, leaving only the minimum pricing.

To show max pricing only, change

```
wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );
```

to

```
wc_price( $prices[1] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[1] );
```

Below is the code from here: http://www.templatemonster.com/help/woocommerce-how-to-remove-variable-products-available-price-range.html#gref

```
/*
Disable Variable Product Price Range: 
*/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'my_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'my_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );

function my_variation_price_format( $price, $product ) {

// Main Price
$prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ),
$product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
$price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( '%1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

// Sale Price
$prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ),     
$product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
sort( $prices );
$saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( '%1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

if ( $price !== $saleprice ) {
$price = '<del>' . $saleprice . '</del> <ins>' . $price . '</ins>';
}
return $price;
}
```

Comment: I uderstand that. I tried messing with that template file. Which is this one: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.0/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php . But the variation block (with the price and options) is in 1 piece of code. So when i move that single variation-action arround  both the variable-options and the price move. Which is not what i want. I only want the price

Comment: So if the pricing is €50 - €100, did you want it to show the €50 or €100? I just downloaded woocommerce to my test WP, created a variable product and a simple product. Currently both prices are right underneath the title. When I add your code, the whole variable pricing is removed. However, when I add the code from [here](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/woocommerce-how-to-remove-variable-products-available-price-range.html#gref), it just removes the max pricing. I'm trying to duplicate what you see with the price going below the attributes but can't.

Comment: So if you removed your code to display the variable pricing, I assume the variable pricing is where you want it to be (underneath the title). If you want to display the minimum price, use the code from the link above. If you want to display the maximum price, use the code from the link about too but change the "0" to "1" where you see this code wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

Comment: That piece of code is in the correct place yes, but that code will result in 2 different prices. That example doesnt have prices for different variations. The variation price needs to go underneath the title, nut just the minimum or maximum price of a item. I will add a extra image in my original post.

Comment: Some products can have 10 different variations which all can have different prices. So the rage is between €50 - €100 but not only €50 and €100

Comment: OOOOOkies, gotcha!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem (even though I used different means) and now thanks to James Jones code I could finish it up!

My way of working it out looked like this:

I had variations product page where I wanted to hide price range but keep single product price.

I did this using this two CSS snippets:

```
/*Hide Price Range on Variation Product Page*/
.single-product .entry-summary .price {
  display: none;  
}

/*Show and Modify Single Product Price on Variation Product Page*/
.single-product .entry-summary .woocommerce-variation-price .price {
  display: block; 
  color: green !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  margin-top: 12px !important;
  margin-bottom: 16px !important;
}
```

After I did this I wanted to move single product price to the place under the title (where price variation range was before), adding James code to functions.php helped me out achieve this. Thanks!